# Conditional CSS for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, tooltip

I have created some tooltips based on http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/
They work great and look great.

The only issue is that in IE, the "img" is misplaced. Unfortunately, the only way I've been able to get the tooltips to work is by putting the css in th php document itself in a  tag. This precludes me from being able to use an ie.css sheet because the styling in the doc would overrule it, right?

The website is www.cleantelligent.com/cleantelligent-pricing and cleantelligent.com/cleantelligent-pricing/custom-package/

Any idea how I can move those images over so they line up on IE?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, but I fixed it using an !important in the ie.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just used the ie.css sheet and put !important in the line. It's a hack, but it worked.